# How to speed up the importing of the PayPal JS SDK to speed up loading buttons in dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, paypal

I want to display PayPal buttons on my Google Sheet in a dialog. The problem is the dialog takes a long time (3 to 4 seconds) to display after the user initiates the action. I think the problem is happening based on the fact that I import the JS using a CDN and script tag as follows:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SB_CLIENT_ID" />
```

So, after the user clicks the display trigger, they have to wait for the entire CDN to download the package before it can display the dialog. Is there a way to improve the response time? Perhaps by storing the SDK in a local file? Or downloading it and storing the JS in some type of pre-cache that loads when the spreadsheet opens and can be re-used each time the trigger is used? Because this way, it feels like the CDN is downloaded on each display and the performance hit is significant.

How would I accomplish this?

Code.gs

```
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(FILENAME)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, TITLE);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/ -->

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Ensures optimal rendering on mobile devices. -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <!-- Optimal Internet Explorer compatibility -->
</head>

<body>
  <script
    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SB_CLIENT_ID"> // Required. Replace SB_CLIENT_ID with your sandbox client ID.
  </script>

  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

  <script>
    paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');
    // This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: *a long time* - what do you call a long time?

Comment: @JaromandaX: 3 to 4 seconds. I'll edit the question now to be more specific.

Comment: Take a look at the [cache service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service) perhaps that would work for you. But a local file might work just as well.

Comment: @Cooper: But how would I import a local file in my code? GAS does not have `require()` or anything like that. Correct?

Comment: have you broken down what's happening in that 3 to 4 seconds? Browser developer tools are good for such analysis

Comment: Try Googling `how to cache paypal cdn`.  You may actually decide that you don't really want to do that.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal and this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, how about putting the Javascript using Templated HTML? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) In this case, when a dialog is opened, the Javascript is loaded. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.